# What is the correct formulation of Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, logic, logic-translation, rolles-theorem

Generally [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) is expressed with words. But how should it look in a formal mathematical/logic language?

$$\forall f \Big( \big(f \textrm{continue [a,b]} \land f \textrm{differentiable ]a,b[} \land f(a)=f(b) \big) \rightarrow \exists c \in ]a,b[\textrm{ s.t. }f'(c)=0 \Big)$$

$$\forall f \Big( (f \textrm{continue [a,b]} \land f \textrm{differentiable ]a,b[ }) ( f(a)=f(b) \rightarrow \exists c \in ]a,b[\textrm{ s.t. }f'(c)=0) \Big)$$

So where should we **place** $f(a)=f(b)$ ?

Comment: The correct way to formulate it is with words.  Math is hard enough without couching everything in formal statements that have to be decoded.

Comment: the 2 options are fine but the 1st is prettier

Comment: @saulspatz For such a famous theorem we should have a precise formulation ;-)

Comment: We have an exact formulation, stated in words.

Comment: The grammar is wrong in the second. You need to omit the "if". ("If A then B" and "A implies B" mean the same thing, but "if A implies B" is something else...)

Comment: @saulspatz It can be very interesting to represent statements/theorems in formal language. For example, representing numbers with predicate logic has interesting implications for the philosophy of mathematics (particularly epistemology).

Comment: @N.Bar I don't deny that.  I'm objecting to the word "correct."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two formulations are logically equivalent. Indeed, $(A \land B) \to C$ is logically equivalent to $A \to (B \to C)$ (you can check it by yourself by truth table). This equivalence is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in several contexts of mathematics and theoretical computer science.

Note that, to be more precise, the correct formalization of the second sentence is 
\begin{equation}
\forall f \, \big( (f \text{ cont. }[a,b] \land f \text{ diff. } ]a,b[) \to (f(a) = f(b) \to \exists c (c \in {]a,b[} \land f'(c) = 0)) \big)
\end{equation}
(notice the nested implications).